# grep OR condition in a look ahead

Tags: regex, grep

I have logfiles with data as shown below and I am trying to extract part of the lines using `grep`.

**Data:**

```
Wed Nov 11|09:14:00.750|I|39|Dispatched message : uID : A13549123c, MSG : Some message here. Can be any amount of chars and contain anything., MSGREFNUM : 12948230158AASJKDHACNBMAMNSBD, Sender : IamSender|com.uws.wamg2.MessDisp|dispatchMessage|123
Wed Nov 11|09:58:01.928|I|41|Dispatched message : uID : 09qwCA0erR, MSG : Some other message without REFNUMcrap.
```

**To extract the MSG from line1:**

```
grep -o -P '(?<=MSG : ).*(?=, MSGREFNUM)' testfile
```

Returns:

```
Some message here. Can be any amount of chars and contain anything.
```

The second line will never contain MSGREFNUM, just a "." and a newline.

I was thinking perhaps "^" could be used to match newline but it didn't work.
Perhaps it would be better to match for "MSG : blabla AND not MSGREFNUM"?

How can I add an OR criteria *(eg. "\|" or similar) in grep so that grep will catch both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
grep -oP '(?<=MSG : )(?:.*(?=, MSGREFNUM)|.*)' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yU1rE3/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=MSG : )` lookbehind which looks next to `MSG :`
- `(?:` start of of a non-capturing group.
- `.*(?=, MSGREFNUM)` At first, this pattern should be executed. So it matches all the characters which exists before `, MSGREFNUM`. Now the regex engine should look the next pattern.
- `|` OR
- `.*` This matches all the characters upto the last. Note that this applies only to the remaining lines (ie, *lines where `, MSGREFNUM` substring does not exist*).

Comment: Cool! Could you explain it a bit? I would've thought something like `(?=(, MSGREFNUM|\.))`.